# Dual boot with Mint and Windows doesn't work: only Linux boot

Tags: linux, boot, windows

What I did so far:

I had Ubuntu + Windows 10, was working fine but Ubuntu was taking too much space on my drive.

Deleted Ubuntu partitions, gave the space back to windows, boot into the Windows USB drive to perform the `bootrec /fixmbr`,`fixboot` commands
Although `bootrec /scanos` didn't detect any Windows installation...I think that's why it doesn't work now. Did the `rebuiuldbcd`, didn't do anything either.

Anyway at this point I rebooted and it worked like a charm, my Windows was loading properly every time.

Now I installed Mint after having an issue with "grub-efi-amd64​ package failed to install to /target/"
In order to solve this I had to do something quite ballsy to me at least

I have an SSD 256 GB with Windows on it and a HD 2 TB on which I wanted to install Linux. 
For some very strange reason the boot partition was apparently on the HD, which is weird I would assume it would be on the SSD. 
Anyway I deleted the NTFS boot partition and created a 500 MB FAT32 boot + esp partition instead. 
After setting this to be the boot partition it worked, the installation finished successfully.

Then reboot, at first I had no grub menu and it was booting directly to Mint, searching the web I ended up modifying the `/etc/default/grub` file and perform a grub-update.

Worked; I now have the grub menu but no Windows is listed.

I tried to run the repair-boot application, it worked, reinstalled everything, but still no Windows.

os-prober doesn't return anything
Only Linux is listed when performing the grub-update command.

```
fdisk -l command 

"Disque /dev/sda : 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 octets, 3907029168 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x6eefb801

Périphérique Amorçage      Début        Fin   Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sda1    *              2048    1026047    1024000   500M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/
/dev/sda2                1026048 3789838335 3788812288   1,8T 83 Linux
/dev/sda3             3789838336 3805462527   15624192   7,5G 82 partition d'éch
/dev/sda4             3805462528 3907028934  101566407  48,4G 83 Linux




Disque /dev/sdb : 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 octets, 488397168 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x6eefb808

Périphérique Amorçage     Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sdb1                  2048 486547455 486545408   232G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2             486547456 487469055    921600   450M 27 TFS WinRE masquée
/dev/sdb3             487471104 488392703    921600   450M 27 TFS WinRE masquée


Disque /dev/sdc : 3,8 GiB, 4009754624 octets, 7831552 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x2f9b3b55

Périphérique Amorçage Début     Fin Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sdc1    *           63 7831551  7831489   3,8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)"
```

I've looked on the Internet but I have to say that I'm stuck, it may have something to do with the Windows side of thing, but still, the issue is in grub so I'm unsure.

Comment: In order to avoid such problems in the future you need to take some time to learn and understand UEFI, how it is different from the old BIOS, why you should install all modern OSes in UEFI mode in UEFI machines, its requirements for both Windows and Linux. Also about partitions and partitions table.

Comment: Actually I was able to recreate the windows boot partition using a lot of diskpart command to delete the partition then recreate it in fat32, then use bcdboot to copy the files from windows. I can boot into windows or linux separately, but I never have a real dual boot choice, I don't really mind at this point. What I mind though is that now I don't have any D drive anymore, everythings fine on the c drive but no more d, it's still there with all the data, but unable to mount it, even with diskpart or disk management. Anyone got any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Pfiou found my way alone, it was hard

Here are two videos that helped me, for the boot recovery, although I had to do way more than this, like deleting partition and recreating it from diskpart, which wasn't obvious:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_I4K2-Rr_Y

And for the D drive not appearing

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=oIdudx8SscA

I used AOMEI partition assistant as it is free, contrary to minitool which didn't have the set ID thing on the free version

Solved